4 statements were executed, 2 of which were duplicated, 2 unique - laravel 8 (using laratrust package)
I'm using laravel Debug bar and everytime I'm try to login in my dashboard (laravel 8) application see alot of number of queries like these
4 statements were executed, 2 of which were duplicated, 2 unique
select * from users where id = 2 and users.deleted_at is null limit 1
select roles.*, role_user.user_id as pivot_user_id, role_user.role_id as pivot_role_id, role_user.user_type as pivot_user_type from roles inner join role_user on roles.id = role_user.role_id where role_user.user_id = 2 and role_user.user_type = 'App\Models\User'
select roles.*, role_user.user_id as pivot_user_id, role_user.role_id as pivot_role_id, role_user.user_type as pivot_user_type from roles inner join role_user on roles.id = role_user.role_id where role_user.user_id = 2 and role_user.user_type = 'App\Models\User'
select permissions.*, permission_user.user_id as pivot_user_id, permission_user.permission_id as pivot_permission_id, permission_user.user_type as pivot_user_type from permissions inner join permission_user on permissions.id = permission_user.permission_id where permission_user.user_id = 2 and permission_user.user_type = 'App\Models\User'
and when I refresh the browser they change to 2 quires only
what is the problem and what causes that ?
Knowing that it is only starter dashboard and I don't add any users and i another application i (laravel 9) have more than 61 queries also due to rules and permessions
I tried to solve it and did not achieve any results
